# Flyway and different paths

Tags: sql, schema, flyway, snowflake-schema

I have sql files in 5 separate folders. I manage versions within each folder as below. All these sqls go under the same schema in the database. Is there a way to create .sql files under these folders and deploy in one shot in Flyway? Thanks in advance!

```
/folder 1
  v1.0.0__create-tablea.sql
  v1.0.1__create-tableb.sql


/folder 2
  v0.0.1__create-table1.sql
  v0.0.2__update-table1.sql


/folder 3
  v1.0.0__create-table1.sql
  v1.0.1__create-table2.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

If you set your configuration file to a folder like this:

```
flyway.locations=filesystem:./sql
```

Then you list the folders that you have under the ./sql folder:

```
./sql/folder 1
./sql/folder 2
./sql/folder 3
```

In that case, each migration from all the folders will be run in the order specified by the naming conventions of Flyway.

However, you have a problem. You've got multiple files with the same prefix:

```
./sql/folder 1/v1.0.1__create-tableb.sql
./sql/folder 3/v1.0.1__create-table1.sql
```

That's going to give you errors. So, yeah, you can readily break up your scripts into different folders under the main one and have them all be part of a single migrate command. You can't however have the same prefix on multiple files.

Comment: Should note, it doesn't have to ./sql. It can be whatever. You just have to define a root location and then put the other folders under that root. Sorry for any lack of clarity.